# Correct form of Lorentz force equation

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, units, si-units, unit-conversion

When I was reading the first volume of the theoretical minimum by Leonard Susskind, I encountered upon this:

[image]

But when I checked Griffiths and all my other electricity and magnetism books, it showed $$\mathbf F=q({\mathbf v} \times \mathbf B)$$ instead. Where did the extra factor of $c$ come from? Which one is the correct equation? Are both equations equivalent? Or was that a misprint in Susskind's book?

Comment: Check the units. F=q(vxB) is for SI units. The Susskind expression is probably for some variant of cgs units.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186811/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. It breaks search functionality and creates problems for blind people.

Comment: Susskind is using Gaussian units, in which the electric field and the magnetic field have the same dimensions and there are no silly $\epsilon_0$ and $\mu_0$ constants. Physics is much nicer in these units. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the units of electromagnetism you are using. The straight-$\vec v$ form is characteristic of SI-style units  where $\nabla\times E=-\dot B$ while the cgs-style units where $\nabla\times E=-\dot B/c$ have $\vec v/c.$

I actually don't know a great way to derive this from the Maxwell's equations directly, but if you know some relativity then you can get it indirectly by looking at $$F^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu -\partial^\nu A^\mu.$$