# Relationship between H and B

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

In a book, it is derived that, in cyclotron, the radius is:

$$r=\frac{mcv}{eH\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

If I let $v\ll c$, then I will get

$$r=\frac{mcv}{eH}$$

However, in classical physics, we have

$$r=\frac{mv}{eB}$$

Then does it mean

$$B=\frac{H}{c}$$

But isn't that

$$B=\mu H\,?$$

Comment: I am not quite sure what you're asking, but indeed $B=\mu H$ is the correct relationship between the H field and the B field.

Comment: The first formula for the radius you have mentioned being in the book is wrong. It probably has terms missing. Relativistic corrected radius is given by $\frac{mv}{eB\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$. and B is definitely = $\mu$H

Comment: The formulas are using different systems of units. See [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63584/cgs-units-for-magnetism).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly by asking this question you betray your age as the formula is not in SI units but in centimetre-gramme second (cgs) units.

In the cgs system there were two sets of units:
electrostatic units - esu
electromagnetic units - emu

In the emu system $H$ was measured in oersteds $\left(1 {\rm Oe} = \dfrac{10^{4}}{4 \pi} {\rm Am^{-1}}\right)$
and $B$ was measured in gauss $\left(1 {\rm G} = 10^{-4} {\rm T}\right)$

Also the permeability of free space $\mu_o$ was set as equal to one in the emu system.

You will note from the conversion factors out comes a familiar constant $4 \pi \times 10^{-7}$ the permeability of free space in ${\rm Hm^{-1}}$.

And if that not complicated enough there was a conversion factor between 1 esu of charge and 1 emu of charge ( $1$ emu of charge = $\dfrac 1 c$ esu of charge where c is the speed of light in cm s$^{-1}$.)

So are you not glad that you are young?

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not too young, I am just not knowledgeable enough. :-)