# Finding a substitution of $\mu_0$ to convert from SI to c.g.s in EM laws

Tags: electromagnetism, units, unit-conversion

In c.g.s, we set $$k=\frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0}=1$$

which gives $$\epsilon_0=\frac 1{4\pi}$$

This conversion works, for example, in Gauss' law:

in SI $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}=\frac\rho{\epsilon_0}$$ and in c.g.s $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E}=4\pi\rho$$

Now, we know $c^2=\frac 1{\epsilon_0\mu_0}$, so in order to convert $\mu_0$ (that usually appears in the SI form) into c.g.s, I thought the substitution would be $$\mu_0=\frac {4\pi}{c^2}$$

However, this doesn't yield the correct laws in c.g.s.

For example, Amper's law in SI is $$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\vec{j}$$

But in c.g.s it is $$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}=\frac {4\pi}c \vec{j}$$
And not $$\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}=\frac {4\pi}{c^2} \vec{j}$$

as I would have expected. So it seems $\mu_0=\frac{4\pi}c$ is the correct substitution.

How can that be? Where did one $c$ go? What is another assumption I am missing?

Comment: You are mixing up different CGS system, I am afraid. Look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre–gram–second_system_of_units), specifically the table in the section "Various extensions of the CGS system to electromagnetism".

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis That actually answers my question, thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of the existence of a few variations to c.g.s.
It seems that in my course, we are using the Gaussian c.g.s units, which explains why Amper's law appears as it does, with $c$ in the denominator. (I just used the constants written in the table you mentioned in Wiki and the Maxwell equations in system-independent form as seen under the table).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CGS Units for Magnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63584/cgs-units-for-magnetism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming $c^2\,\mu_0\,\epsilon_0=1$, which is a formula that holds in SI units but *not in all unit systems*. I find the best "mnemonic" to keep track of all this stuff is the following generalized unit version of Maxwell's equations, detailed in the ["Rationalization" section of the Lorentz-Heaviside unit system Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units#Rationalization):

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} &= \rho / \beta, \\
 \quad \nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &= 0, \\
 \quad \kappa \nabla \times \mathbf{E} &= -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}, \\
 \quad \kappa \nabla \times \mathbf{H} &= \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{J} / \beta,
\end{align}$$

where $\beta$ and $\kappa$ are in general dimensionful units that define the unit system in question. From this set it is clear we must in general use:

$$c^2\,\mu_0\,\epsilon_0=\kappa^2$$

and Gaussian units have $\kappa=c;\,\beta=\frac{1}{4\pi}$. The reason for your "anomaly" should now be clear from the above equation. Of course, often people define their time and length units to be the same, in which case $c=1$ and the problem doesn't arise.

I empathize: this is one of the things I am really bad at - I trip up on units all the time too. If you're like me you really need to keep a few sharp mnemonics like the above handy so that you can get an overall view of what you're doing rather than blindly plugging into conversion formulas.